# Generic Interface, Implementation and Dependency Injection - Implementation Type Can't Be Converted To Service Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection, blazor

I have the following generics (code removed for brevity, I don't think its necessary for the question):

```cs
// ## Entity interface

public interface IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    TPrimaryKey Id { get; set; }
}

// ## Entity implementations

public class Entity<TPrimaryKey> : IEntity<TPrimaryKey> { ... }

public class Entity : Entity<string> { ... }

// ## Repo interfaces

public interface IAsyncRepository<TPrimaryKey, TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity<TPrimaryKey> { ... }

public interface IAsyncRepository<TEntity> : IAsyncRepository<string, TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity<string> {...}

// ## Repo implementations

public class AsyncRepository<TPrimaryKey, TEntity>
    : IAsyncRepository<TPrimaryKey, TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity<TPrimaryKey> { ... }

public class AsyncRepository<TEntity> : AsyncRepository<string, TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity { ... }
```

I then dependency-inject the `AsyncRepositories` as follows:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(AsyncRepository<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<,>), typeof(AsyncRepository<,>));
```

However, when I attempt to inject into my `razor` page using `@inject IAsyncRepository<Account> accountRepository`, I get an error saying:

> System.ArgumentException: Implementation type 'AsyncRepository`1[Account]' can't be converted to service type 'IAsyncRepository`1[Account]'

But, if I change the declaration of the final `AsyncRepository` class as follows then it works:

```cs
public class AsyncRepository<TEntity> : IAsyncRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity
```

Unfortunately I now have code duplication as I need to re-implement the interface.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: is that works : `services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<Account>), typeof(AsyncRepository<Account>));` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars Nope, this also does not work. If I add your suggested line, the application crashes during the `Main` function with the same error as above.

Comment: and with : `public class AsyncRepository<TEntity> : AsyncRepository<string, TEntity>, IAsyncRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity { ... }` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars Aha, that does work!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository must implement `IAsyncRepository<TEntity>` : update your `AsyncRepository<TEntity>` declaration with :

```cs
public class AsyncRepository<TEntity> : AsyncRepository<string, TEntity>,
IAsyncRepository<TEntity>
where TEntity : Entity { ... }
```

Comment: Somehow I missed that in all the configuration folderal.  Thanks, man.